# Ajax Loader

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, javascript

Имеется вывод постов с подгрузкой на WP, по типу Вк или Facebook. Нужно сделать появление loader.gif при прокрутке страницы вниз, именно в тот момент, когда подгружаются новые посты.
Опробовал многие готовые решения, но ничего не удалось применить. 
Как можно сделать?

Код подгрузчика:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bottomOffset = 2000; // отступ от нижней границы сайта, до которого должен доскроллить пользователь, чтобы подгрузились новые посты
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page' : current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && !$('body').hasClass('loading')){
            $.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl,
                data:data,
                type:'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr){
                    $('body').addClass('loading');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) { 
                        $('#true_loadmore').before(data);
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');
                        current_page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все просто. У $.ajax есть такие штуки, как beforeSend (до отправки запроса) и complete (когда запрос сделан)

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Так понял, что при выполнении ajax запросов, будет показываться id="loader"? Или не так понял?

Comment: @bakusite Совершенно верно. Лоадер будет показан, пока идет запрос

Comment: Но он не хочет исчезать((

Сделал так:

<script>
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="loader">Loading...</div>

Comment: @bakusite если вы только это написали, то правильно. У вас же куда-то запрос должен идти, посты подгружаться и все такое http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Можно это установить через $.ajaxSetup({/*те же параметры*/}), но тогда лоадер будет появляться на каждый ajax-запрос через jQuery

Comment: @RedMonkey Именно поэтому стоит найти сам подгрузчик постов и допилить его :)

Comment: @inferusvv Полностью согласен, но это скорее так, для информации

Comment: Добавил в вопрос код самого подгрузчика, но что именно с ним делать, чтобы добавить loader?

Comment: тогда надо менять в css:

    body.loading #loader { display: block; } #loader { display: none; }

Comment: вообще в этом коде плохо то, что лоадер убирается только в случае успешно выполненного запроса, поэтому я бы рекомендовал добавить обработчик complete: function () {$('body').removeClass('loading');} и выкосить соответствующую строчку из success